# Performance of recursive function in register based compiler

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I have a question of whether there will be a performance hit when we write recursive functions in Register based compilers like DVM. I'm aware that recursion isn't recommended in compilers with limited depth like compilers for python.

Comment: "compilers with limited depth like python": Python is not a compiler and its recursion limit is a parameter. AFAIK, not especially low by default. I see no reason to avoid recursion, unless when it is a poor algorithmic choice.

Answer (score 2):

Being register-based does not help for recursive functions, they still have the same problem: conceptually, every call creates a new stack frame. If that is implemented literally, then a recursive call is inherently a little slower than looping, and perhaps more importantly, uses up a finite resource so the recursion depth is limited. A register-based code representation does not have the concept of an operand stack, but that concept is mostly disjoint from the concept of a call stack, which is still necessary just to have general subroutines. Subroutines can be implemented without a call stack if recursion is banned, in which case they need not be re-entrant so the local variables and the variable that holds the return address can be statically allocated.

Going through a trampoline works around the stack growth by quickly returning to a special caller that then calls the continuation, that way recursion doesn't grow the stack at all since the old frame gets deallocated before a new one is created, but it adds even more run-time overhead. Tail call elimination by rewriting the call into a jump achieves a similar effect but by reusing the same frame, with less associated overhead, this requires explicit support from the VM.

Both of those techniques apply equally to stack based and register based representations of the code, which incidentally is primarily a difference in the format in which the code is stored, and need not reflect a difference in the way the code is actually executed: a JIT compiler can turn both of them into whatever form the machine requires.